# The html web applications Type Error with python

Tags: python, html, sql, pandas, flask

I am trying to insert data into sql database by using python. I am using windows authentication not sql server authentication. I have defined the configurations and HTML. I want to insert the data when the button is clicked but the problem is , when I try to insert the data , its giving me error **TypeError
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable**

Here is the config.py

```
# SQL Server Database Connection Properties

DATABASE_CONFIG ={
    'Driver': 'SQL Server',
    'Server': 'NIRJOR\KHUNDOKERNIRJOR',
    'Database': 'HalifaxDatabase',
    'UID': '',
    'Password': ''
    }
```

Here is the code for connections.

```
import pypyodbc
import config

# Return the sql connection 
def getConnection():
     connection = pypyodbc.connect("Driver= {"+config.DATABASE_CONFIG["Driver"]+"} ;Server=" + config.DATABASE_CONFIG["Server"] + ";Database=" + config.DATABASE_CONFIG["Database"] + ";uid=" + config.DATABASE_CONFIG["UID"] + ";pwd=" + config.DATABASE_CONFIG["Password"])
     return connection
```

Here is the code main.py.

```
import flask
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask,redirect
import db_connection as dbConn
import config
from flask import request
@app.route('/add_loan', methods=[ 'POST'])
def add_loan():

    if request.method == "POST":
        Account_Number = request.form['Account_Number']
        Loan_Amount = request.form['Loan_Amount'],
        Monthly_Payment = request.form['Monthly_Payment'],
        Interest_Rate = request.form['Interest_Rate']
        Loan_Tram = request.form['Loan_Tram'],
            
        connection = dbConn.getConnection()

        insert_query = '''INSERT INTO Loan_Details (Account_Number, Loan_Amount, Monthly_Payment, Interest_Rate, Loan_Tram) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);'''
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(insert_query,[Account_Number, Loan_Amount, Monthly_Payment, Interest_Rate, Loan_Tram])    
        connection.commit()
        return redirect (url_for('CompleteApplication'))

    return render_template("CompleteApplication.html")
    
      
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here is the html.

```
<form class="form-detail" action="{{ url_for('add_loan') }}" method="POST" id="myform">
                    <div class="form-left">
                        <h2>Loan Infomation</h2>
                        <div class="form-group">
                           
                            <div class="form-row form-row-1">
                                <input type="text" name="Account_Number" id="Account_Number" class="input-text" placeholder=" Enter Account Numer" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row form-row-2">
                                <input type="text" name="Loan_Amount" id="Loan_Amount" class="input-text" placeholder="Enter Loan Amount" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row form-row-3">
                                <input type="text" name="Monthly_Payment" id="Monthly_Payment" class="input-text" placeholder="Monthley Payment" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row form-row-5">
                                <input type="text" name="Interest_Rate" id="Interest_Rate" class="input-text" placeholder="Interest Rate" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-row form-row-6">
                                <input type="text" name="Loan_Tram" id="Loan_Tram" class="input-text" placeholder="Enter Loan Tram " required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-row-last">
                                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="register" value="Complete">
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Here is the Traceback when I    clicked the submit button.
[image]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which line makes problem.

Comment: I used console and its working perfectly but with the html not woking

Comment: You are posting data though the html post methods not via cursor

Comment: `"not woking"` is the most useless information. I will repeate: always put **FULL** error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Traceback is added  @furas

Comment: cursor.execute(insert_query,[Account_Number, Loan_Amount, Monthly_Payment, Interest_Rate, Loan_Tram]) line highlated on traceback but I can not find the error

Comment: you stil didn't show **FULL** error message - there can be other lines very useful for us (but maybe not for you). So ALWAYS show FULL error message.

Comment: if error show you line with problem then first you could use `print(...)`, `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables in this line. It is called `"print debuging"`. You may have value different then you expect and using `print()` you may check it.

Comment: Which line of the code the print methods needs to add ?

Comment: The values is coming from the input fields

Comment: and which lines you see in error message? `cursor.execute(...)`! Then use `print()` before this line and display all variables which you use in this line. And it doesn't matter that you get it from input field - somewhere is problem and you have to find what is this problem - and first step is to check what you have in variable - you have to debuge code. And don't trust you code - it doesn't matter that it works in console. Now it doesn't work. And  maybe you was running different code in console. And using `print()` you can check it. It is much simpler then learning how to use real debuger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't check if this the only problem
but you have commas `,` at the end of lines

```
    Loan_Amount = request.form['Loan_Amount'],
    Monthly_Payment = request.form['Monthly_Payment'],

    Loan_Tram = request.form['Loan_Tram'],
```

and this is big mistake because comma converts `value` into `tuple` like `(value,)`
so you assign `tuples` instead of expected values.

And later it trie to use tuple `(value,)` instead of `value` in `execute` and this gives error.

Comment: Thanks very much you save my time